# TensorFlow installation on Win7x64 (no matching distribution / not a supported wheel)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get TensorFlow to work on my Win7x64 following this guide:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Everything has gone well until `3. Install the TensorFlow pip package`

When i do "`python`" to see the version i get the following:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:57:15) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

When i do "`pip install tensorflow`" i get:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement of tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

If i try "`python -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`" i get this:

```
tensorflow-1.2.1-cp55-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

Please help me understand what am i doing wrong or why is it not working? How to get it to work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unsupported version of Python. Tensorflow currently only supports Python 3.6 and below, not 3.7 and even if you do manage to install it you will run into issues as Python 3.7 made `async` a keyword and many libraries, like Tensorflow, use this for variable names. In order to make this work on your system you need to downgrade to 3.6, there is actually a thread with troubleshooting steps on this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022